# div always on top of fixed element

Tags: javascript, html, css

what I'm trying to do is simple to tell. There is fixed div on my page on bottom. It must be always shown on bottom, so position fixed is used.

In this div there are 2divs, one small must be always on top of this fixed div, another must be scrollable.

The problem is small div, if I give him position fixed, it is position to top of window, not on top of this fixed div, as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfEfL/)

If small div is position absolute, it is on top of fixed div, but if it is scrolled, as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfEfL/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="bottom">
 <div class="top"></div>
 <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bottom
{
    padding:20px;
    height: 253px; 
    position: fixed; 
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: red;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.top
{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

.content
{
    height: 1500px;
    background: linear-gradient(green, blue);
}
```

Is is possible to make this work without watching scrolling by jvascript? By pure CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a wrapper `<div>` for the content and let it scroll - so that the absolutely positioned sibling does not scroll along with it, as follows:

HTML

```
 <div class="bottom">
   <div class="top"></div>
      <div class='contentWrap'>
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.contentWrap{
 height:100%;
 overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bottom {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 253px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.top {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
.contentWrap {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px; /* .top height - .bottom padding*/
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.content {
  height: 1500px;
  background: linear-gradient(green, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class='contentWrap'>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pfEfL/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach using fixed -> absolute is absolutely correct since you can position an element absolute but relative to its parent by doing so. The problem is that the absolute .top always appears on top of .bottom - so if .bottom is scrolled, .top will follow.

My solution would be using `position:fixed;` on .top, but using bottom instead of top:

```
.top {
    ....
    position:fixed;
    bottom:253px; /*note sure how it should look at the end, try it yourself*/
 }
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a minute. Anyway if you want it to be at the very top of the div use 'bottom: 243px;' instead. To compensate for the 10px padding on top/bottom of your div.

Answer (score 0):

Add `div` with class `top` inside `div` with class `content` and remove `top:0` from `.top` class:

**html**

```
<div class="bottom">  
    <div class="content" >
        <div class="top"></div>
    </div>
<div>
```

**css**

```
.top
{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfEfL/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it basically just puts a frame container around your scrollable div to keep everything in place. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/s4HBG/)

```
<div class="bottom">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="scroll-container">
        <div class="content" ></div>
    </div>
<div>

.scroll-container 
{
    height: 203px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Also, remove `overflow-y: scroll;` from the `.bottom` class

Answer (score 0):

If you already dealing with fixed heights & positions, why not just position the 'top' section as fixed as well? check the <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pfEfL/11/)</kbd>
like so:

```
.top
{
    height:50px;
    bottom:243px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
}
```